# Share password in several LastPass entries

Tags: passwords, lastpass

Some of my login credentials are actually linked (via LDAP I guess) to a Windows Active Directory account. That means, the entries in my LastPass account for those refer to the same password which, according to AD policies, must be updated regularly. I have three problems with this:

1. How to find the passwords which must be updated whenever I perform an AD password update? I have solved this by placing all entries linked to the AD account into an "AD" group in LastPass, and manually updating those entries whenever the AD credentials change.
2. DRY? (Don't Repeat Yourself). How can I have a single entry referring to the AD credentials, and link the rest of the entries to this entry?
3. LastPass "Security Challenge" becomes useless, since I get lots of non-relevant "Change Reused Passwords" warnings.

Can you suggest a good approach to solve all this problems?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with multiple active directory logins stored. Here's how I've solved it, though I can't claim it's the best way. It just works for me.

At my company we have multiple domains (parent company and child companies). So lets use foobarenterprises.com, foo.com, and bar.com.

The first thing I did was setup Equivalent Domains (Account Settings > Equivalent Domains tab). This is just a single entry that is a comma seperated list of those domains. So with that setup, it will now recognize that all three domains can use passwords with each other (a saved login for foo.com would work as well for bar.com or foobarenterprises.com).

The second thing I did was to remove ALL entries with that user account. I then created a single entry that I named "AD Account" (or whatever you prefer). I set the URL to foo.com (which saves as http://foo.com) and set my username and password.

Now when I browse to any site in those domains, I can use my single saved entry to login. Though my autocompletion doesn't seem to work well... not sure if this is Lastpass or the sites I'm trying to log into though.

I hope others will post how they do this because I'm curious to know if there are better ways. But hopefully this will help some.  Good luck!